# Jira: estimate of story = sum of estimates on subtasks under the story

Tags: jira, estimation, jira-agile

I just started using Jira and can not seem to figure out how to automate calculation of hours on "Story". I create Stories and under them subtasks with estimated time. Was expecting by default to get sum of subtasks estimates as an estimate for Story. However it stays empty.

Any configuration I missed?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this functionality is not currently available in JIRA.

There is an open feature request [detailed here](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JSW-9167).

The discussion in this feature request does mention some workarounds, but they require additional plug-ins.